# c++ how to determine whether one word is before another in the alphabet

Tags: c++, function, compare, alphabetical

I'm using the `sort()` function in C++ to sort a vector of objects of type 'Game', which I defined myself.  To do this, I am manually writing a function that will act in place of the `operator<`, and which will be passed as the third parameter to the `sort()` function.  First, I compare based on scores.  Then, if scores are tied, I compare based on team name.

What I need is a function `alphabetical(string s1, string s2)`, that will return true if `s1` would come before `s2` in the dictionary.  For example:

```
alphabetical("aardvark", "apple"); //true
alphabetical("balloon", "zebra"); //true
alphabetical("zebra", "apple"); //false
```

I also want it to return false if the strings are identical.  Is there something in a library that I could use?  Or, how would I write the function?  I hope I'm coming across clearly.

Comment: If everything's lower-case ASCII, with no special collation sequence, you can use `strcmp`.

Comment: You can also use `std::lexicographical_compare`.

Comment: `operator<` and `operator>` works with strings (I think). Because `"a" < "b"` returns true (though my compiler warns that this is undefined behavior).

Comment: @David, That's comparing addresses. Never reliable. `std::string` does support `operator<` etc., though.

Comment: @David: `"a" < "b"` is comparing `char*`; you want `std::string("a") < std::string("b")` instead, barring of course any implicit conversions you might like to use.

Comment: @chris not true - it is always reliable it just doesnt do what it seems like it does :-) in other high level languages

Comment: `std::string::operator<()` is defined as being equivalent to `std::lexicographical_compare()`. So if you have `char*`'s you should just use the latter.

Comment: @AdrianCornish, Yes, I just meant you have almost no way of telling what it will be before you try it.

Comment: @chris just joking with your answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` implements a lexicographical less-than comparison operator itself, meaning that `stringA < stringB` should usually do what you want. If you create a `std::list<std::string> words`, sorting alphabetically will be as simple as `words.sort();`

Your custom `Game` class could have its less-than comparison operator implemented simply as:

```
return (score < rhs.score) || (score == rhs.score && team < rhs.team)
```

It is worth noting that lexicographical sorting will not always be what a human would expect. Jeff Atwood goes into a discussion of so-called "natural sort order" versus lexicographical sort order in [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html). His post also provides resources from which you will be able to find algorithms if such sorting is necessary to you.

Comment: not just symbols and numbers, which who knows what one would expect when they say "alphabetical", but also case sensitivity becomes an issue.  See my answer and responses to others here.

Comment: My team names are such that the first character is capitalized and all others are lowercase.  The < operator works.

Answer (score 1):

A standard string comparison will work if your strings are all upper or lower.  I believe it even works with character encodings that are not used anymore, such as EBSIDIC or whatever.

If you'll have mixed case then this does not work because 'A' is greater than 'z'.  For this to work you'll want to use things like stricmp or whatever.  You can also override char_traits for your basic_string to do insensitive comparison.

If you want to write the sort such that it places 'A' before 'a' or visa-versa but 'b' after 'a'...then you'll need to write your own.  It should be fairly simple using the ASCII table, which most operating systems today use.

If you have to support languages other than English the problem actually becomes non-trivial.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `std::string`s you can just use `<`. But if you already have `char*`, you don't want to (or can't) change that, and you want to avoid the overhead of converting to `std::string`, then you can use `std::lexicographical_compare()`.

Of course, in both cases, you probably want a case-insensitive comparison. Offhand I'm not sure what the right solution is for `std::string`, probably something to do with `char_traits`, but for `lexicographical_compare()` you can provide a comparator:

```
bool alphabetical(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(str1, &str1[strlen(str1)], str2, &str2[strlen(str2)], [](char a, char b){
        return tolower(a) < tolower(b);
    });
}
```

Comment: @CrazyEddie, Isn't it? What is it then? It's been a long time since I've looked or used it, but I thought it would be alphabetical (at least case-sensitive-wise).

Comment: @chris - In lexi comparison, which is simply the code compare, 'A' comes after 'z'.  Alphabetically we would at least expect both 'a' and 'A' to come before 'b' or 'B'.  This can be replicated with insensitive lexi comparison.  If 'A' should appear before 'a' though then there's nothing standard that will do.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: You make a good point, but you didn't have to go downvoting every other answer besides yours.

Comment: @Kevin - I did if I think the rest are wrong.  I downvote incorrect responses.  If that bothers you, grow a pair I guess.  Downvote is for unhelpful responses.  Incorrect answers are worse than unhelpful IMO.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: Minor issues in otherwise-correct answers do not make the entire answer unhelpful. If you see an error, you can comment, pointing it out, and giving the author of the answer time to correct the issue. Only if the answer as a whole is wrong should you go ahead and downvote.

Comment: Stop karma whoring dude.  It's just points.  You were wrong, be right next time...and don't cry about it.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: What an incredibly rude person you are. This is a place for discussion about coding, not a place for you to stroke your own ego. My, what a rush you must have experienced as your sharp eagle-eyes noticed the small error in someone else's answer, and how quick your hand was on that mouse as you swooped in to downvote that other answer, thus ensuring that your own answer was at the top of the pile.

Comment: Yeah, it's my ego that needs to be stroked...that's why I'm freaking out big time about being down -2 for someone downvoting me.  Bet it was you, revenge voting...but who's the one crying?  Calling me rude for downvoting your just plain wrong answer is not going to make me reverse the vote.  In fact, now that you've done so...you're not going to be able to make me reverse it...which you'll note I did on another increasing his points even above what mine were before your revenge vote.  Look in a mirror or whatever.  Take a toke or something...