# Checking if a text file is in alphabetical order

Tags: c++

I have the following code it scans a text file and gets several lines, I'm trying to implement some input validation so if the user inputs a wrong file, it prompts the user and closes the program instead of crashing. I've currently added a few things but I'm trying to implement something to check if the file is sorted in alphabetical...

I've currently tried `sort(word.begin(), word.end());`
 but this sorts the words... I don't actually want to sort the words I just want to check if theyre in alphabetical order if not, close the program... How can I achieve this?

the layout of the file is

`word`

`definition`

`type`

`blankline`

repeat...

for example

```
a
the letter a 
n

b
the letter b
n

c  
the letter c  
n

...end
```

Comment: Please don't post your whole code, only relevant parts. Also, please give us some info as to how your input files look like.

Comment: Read one word at a time. Check if the current word is alphabetically higher than the previous word. If this fails, abort.

Comment: @Barmar I understand what your saying, but I'm unsure how I can code this, if you provide some sort of reference that would be great.

Comment: After you process a word, save it in a variable `previousWord`. Then when you read the next word, compare it to `previousWord`. Try coding it yourself, that's how you learn, not by having other people do your work for you.

Comment: I'm still confused, if I knew it, I wouldn't be asking this question... I understand what I need to do but I'm unsure how to code it.

Comment: @user2881555 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361447/c-how-to-determine-whether-one-word-is-before-another-in-the-alphabet

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to check if the words are alphabetically ordered why don't you check the first and the second strings? If they're in order, you go to your second and third... And so on until one of them is not ordered or the end of file. If you made it to the end it means they're ordered..

```
string word, definition, type, blank, aux;

while (getline(dictionaryFile, word) &&
        getline(dictionaryFile, definition) &&
        getline(dictionaryFile, type) &&
        getline(dictionaryFile, blank)) {

if (strcmp(aux.c_str(), word.c_str()) > 0) return;
    else aux=word; 
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: Since they are already strings they can be compared directly without `strcmp`.

Comment: This code is giving me an error `argument of type "bool" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"`

Comment: sorry, i missed one closed parenthesis before " > 0 "